# Magento 2 : Custom Category Attribute not Showing in Admin

Tags: admin, category, magento-2.1.3, custom-attributes

I am using magento 2.1.3. I have created customer group as a custom attribute while creating category. On my localhost its showing textfield to enter customer group. But on server its not showing text field to enter customer group.

Customer group has been successfully created as an attribute in database in both enviroment i.e localhost and server. Dont know what I am doing wrong. Given full permission to folder also.Please refer the below 2 screens.

I have also clone server database and code in my local enviroment, there its working fine but on server its not.

[image: imgur].com/OgR7C.png

Comment: Have you cleared the cache. Bu the way on which mode you are running?

Comment: have you remove var/generation and clear cache and run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: When you deployed and I assume the code was compiled and the static contend deployed, did you have any errors in the terminal?

Comment: we are running on developer mode. Deleted var/generation and cleared cache still not working :(

Comment: please show your category_form.xml file code.